# I would like to format my list data from a MySQL database into even rows and columns

Tags: html, css

Essentially as the title says. I have looked at other examples but they don't seem to fit my requirements. I am echoing out data from a database to the user in list format. I would like it to appear as even rows and columns when displayed.

here is my current css code

```
.recent_items{
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.item li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.item{
   width:85%;
}
```

and here is the php code for the data

```
<?
                    $per_page = 30;
                    $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ads") or die(mysql_error());
                    $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0)/ $per_page);
                    $curr_page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
                    $start = ($curr_page - 1) * $per_page;

                    //get ad information
                    $ad_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY dateCreated DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page") or die(mysql_error());
                    $rows = mysql_num_rows($ad_info);

                    echo '<ul class="item">';
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ad_info)){
                        $ad_id = $row['adId'];
                        $title = $row['title'];
                        $price = $row['price'];
                        $location = $row['location'];

                        $ad_type = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE adId=$ad_id") or die(mysql_error());
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ad_type)){
                            $cat = $row['category'];
                            $sub = $row['subCat'];

                            echo
                            "
                                <li>$title</br>
                                <label>Price:</label> $price</br>
                                <label>Location:</label> $location</br>
                                <a href=\"search.php?searchValue=".$cat."\">$cat</a>/<a href=\"search.php?searchValue=".$sub."\">$sub</a></li>
                            ";
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';

                    if($pages >= 1 && $curr_page <= $pages){
                        for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++){
                           echo ($x == $curr_page) ? "<b><a href=\"?page=$x\">$x</a></b> " : "<a href=\"?page=$x\">$x</a> ";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

The problem is that css and php code come out looking this:
https://twitter.com/HassanNSaid/status/320364537477996544/photo/1

As you can see the columns are not alined. I tried altering the width but all that happened is a item basically moved up one row.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define a width for your `li` elements.

```
.item li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 25%; /* this would give you four columns */
}
```

The width on `.item` corresponds to the outer container width...your `li` elements determine the column width. Essentially, your saying you want the whole list to occupy 85% of the window width. Since you didn't define a width for the `li` but you did say they should act like inline elements, they will shrink down to fit the inner content (giving you varying widths). By specifying the width of the `li`, you are saying you want them all to be the same. If the content on a line is greater than that width, it will end up wrapping.